# Permanent redirect absolute url

Tags: django, django-views, httpresponse, django-urls

I am struggling with a basic redirect functionality.

I need to redirect all traffic not matching certain paths to another domain.

in my urls.py

```
re_path(r'^(?P<shortcode>[\w-]+)/$', core_views.myView)
```

and the corresponding function in views.py

```
def myView(request, shortcode=None):
    url = 'www.newdomain.cz/' + str(shortcode)
    return HttpResponsePermanentRedirect(url)
```

but what it does is - when called for example [www.olddomain.com/sdfasd](http://www.olddomain.com/sdfasd) it redirects me to [www.olddomain.com/sdfasd/www.newdomain.cz/sdfasd](http://www.olddomain.com/sdfasd/www.newdomain.cz/sdfasd) but I obviously need only [www.newdomain.cz/sdfasd](http://www.newdomain.cz/sdfasd)

what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a fully qualified url.

```
def myView(request, shortcode=None):
    url = 'http://www.newdomain.cz/' + str(shortcode)
```

See the doc [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseRedirect).